# Can I pdo prepare ALL my sql queries in one php file?

Tags: php, pdo

Let's say I make the file below:

database.php

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; charset=utf8; dbname=myDb, username; password");

$sqlMyQuery1 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblTable1 WHERE Column1 = :Column1');
$sqlMyQuery1Param = array(':Column1' => $_POST[FormItem1]);

$sqlMyQuery2 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblTable2 WHERE Column1 = :Column1');
$sqlMyQuery2Param = array(':Column1' => $_POST[FormItem2]);

$sqlMyQuery3 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblTable3 WHERE Column1 = :Column1');
$sqlMyQuery3Param = array(':Column1' => $_POST[FormItem3]);
```

I then include this file to my other php files, so I can just do this on the fly:

```
$sqlMyQuery1 -> execute($sqlMyQuery1Param);
```

Given that in a real wesite, I'll have TONS of queries, will it affect the performance of my website, because I am "preparing" a bunch of queries everytime the page loads?

Comment: Well... I am sure there is a better way to do this but if all your variables are set ($_POST['FormItem1'], etc) and that you dont have 100000000000 millions query I guess you shouldn't see the difference.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as such ;)

Answer (score 1):

This does not only heavily affect performance, but also the RAM usage will skyrocket. From the PHP manual:

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object.

This shows that for every prepare, the database will be queried and an RAM-using object is created. This shouldn't be a big deal for 2-4 statements, but with 10+ statements this will

- put load on your SQL
- therefore put load on your network (if your SQL is located outside)
- create a lot of useless objects
- require a lot of time for this and
- set a lot of variables in your current scope you don't need

You could numerate/name your querys and have a factory which will create it for you, so you could just do

```
factory::getQuery(4)->execute();
```

I have written a code gen for this which makes things a lot easier; it's not ready for the public but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare once , then execute multiple times:

```
$sqlMyQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblTable1 WHERE Column1 = :Column1');

$sqlMyQuery1Param = array(':Column1' => $_POST[FormItem1]);
$sqlMyQuery2Param = array(':Column1' => $_POST[FormItem2]);
$sqlMyQuery3Param = array(':Column1' => $_POST[FormItem3]);

$result1 = $sqlMyQuery-> execute($sqlMyQuery1Param);
```

This will improve performance for sure. Calling `prepare()` on the same query defeats the purpose of prepare statment and could be expensive sometimes.

Comment: Sorry to confuse, but they're different queries, thus the multiple prepare()'s